# Quickblox VideoChat- Not connecting

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat

I'm using the samples in Android sdk. In the video samples i'm able to run the app successfully bu it is not connecting to the chat yet. A progress bar will start running as soon as loginas any user . Here is the log in the logcat

```
19893-19926/com.quickblox.sample.videochatwebrtc D/QBASDK﹕ Connecting to chat..
```

Am i doing something wrong here..?
I have replaced credentials with mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while , I found the solution for this issue. Quickblox sample project is working without any bug, but video chatting is not possible.

```
Quickblox connection is interupted by my network (firewall settings).
```

So, I changed the privacy and it is working nicely,

Cheer Up guys, thanks for your support.